# cleaning GPIO pins using pigpio module?

Tags: gpio, python, raspbian-jessie, pigpio

I am using pigpio module to control 12 GPIO pins of the Raspberry pi. WHich includes PWM reading, software PWM etc.  I couldn't find a method to clean up the pin at the end of the program. Isn't it available in pigpio? any other suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

pigpio makes no assumptions about what state the GPIO are intended to be in at the end of a program.

It is up to the programmer to decide if they should be read, write, set as SPI, PWM etc.